# How to use Spark-Submit to run a scala file present on EMR cluster's master node?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr, spark-submit

So, I connect to my EMR cluster's master node using SSH. This is the file structure present in the master node:

```
|-- AnalysisRunner.scala
|-- AutomatedConstraints.scala
|-- deequ-1.0.1.jar
|-- new
|   |-- Auto.scala
|   `-- Veri.scala
|-- VerificationConstraints.scala
`-- wget-log
```

Now, I would first run
`spark-shell --conf spark.jars=deequ-1.0.1.jar`

And once I got to the scala prompt, I would use `:load new/Auto.scala` to run my scala script.

WHAT I WANT TO DO:

While on my EMR cluster's master node, I would like to run a single `spark-submit` command that would help me achieve exactly what I was doing earlier.

I'm new to this, so can anyone help me with the command?

Comment: What have you tried from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any beginner who might be stuck here:

You will need to have an IDE (I used IntelliJ IDEA).  Steps to follow:

1. Create a scala project - put down all dependencies you need, in the build.sbt file.
2. Create a package (say 'pkg') and under it create a scala object (say 'obj').
3. Define a main method in your scala object and write your logic.
4. Process the project to form a single .jar file. (use IDE tools or run 'sbt package' in your project directory)
5. Submit using the following command

```
spark-submit --class pkg.obj 
--jars <path to your dependencies (if any)> 
<path to the jar created from your code> 
<command line arguments (if any)>
```

This worked for me. Note - if you are running this on an EMR cluster, make sure all paths are specified based on either

1. filesystem present on the cluster
2. an S3 path